# HTML & JS - Add custom parameter to any request

Tags: javascript, html

I have a huge html+php file, and I'm not able to edit it fully. So, is that possible to listen "onClick" on "onSubmit" on any forms? It means that when a user clicks on a link, the parameter automatically adds to this request.
So, if it was http://example.com/file?param1=true
It should stay http://example.com/file?param1=true&customParam=value (this is a static parameter) and it should be with any request get or post

Comment: You submit the form uising `action` attribute or onclick event in javascript?

Comment: @MauricePerry, Yeah, if it's possible, please say how and give an example

Comment: @A.J, the both cases should be covered

Comment: make a demo on jsbin.